# Can I convert this String type variable to Map type in scala language?

Tags: java, scala

Can I convert this String type variable to Map type?
for example...

```
scala> aa.getClass
res35: Class[_ <: Object] = class java.lang.String

scala> aa
res36: Object = Map(MetricName [name=response-rate, group=consumer-node-metrics, description=The average number of responses received per second., tags={client-id=consumer-2, node-id=node--1}] -> org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric@c19540f
```

I would like to change this aa variable to the real Map type of scala.
For reference, the types in the Map are the classes of the Kafka library.

Comment: can you also add the declaration body of `aa`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, `aa` is the result of calling `toString` on some `Map` and you want to know whether it's possible to get the map back from `aa`.

In general the answer is no, because multiple different maps can have the same string representation. Here is an easier-to-see example with `List` instead of `Map`: `List("a","b").toString` is the same as `List("a,b").toString`.

For your specific use-case, you *may* be able to write a parser but I would be surprised if you can find an existing one.